# Can I open folder using $cordovaFileOpener in ionic mobile app?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I can see the example to open file (PDF, mp3 etc) but how to open folder which is created by my app only. I'm not sure what to pass in second argument for file type as I want to open folder.

**Below is not working**

```
$cordovaFileOpener2.open(
        cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + "MyFolder/",
        ''
    ).then(function() {
          // Success!
    }, function(err) {
          // An error occurred. Show a message to the user
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all files of a folder, I use native API. I made a function that receives the path and returns an array of FileEntry.

In ES2015(ES6):

```
function getFiles(path) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, fileSystem => {
      let directoryReader = fileSystem.createReader();
      directoryReader.readEntries(entries => resolve(entries), error => reject(error));
    }, error => reject(error)));
}
```

An example of FileEntry returned by function is:

```
FileEntry {
  isFile: true,
  isDirectory: false,
  name: "file.pdf",
  fullPath: "/Android/data/app/file.pdf",
  filesystem: FileSystem
}
```

In addition, you can open each file with fileOpener2:

```
$cordovaFileOpener2.open(file.nativeURL, 'application/pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

To open all types of files/folder use the following plugin,

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2.git
```

Then use the following code,

```
 $cordovaFileOpener2.open(
    'path',
    'application/*'            
  ).then(function() {
          // Success!
  }, function(err) {
          // An error occurred. Show a message to the user
  });
```

Reference: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileOpener2/